# Postgres server-side cursor with LEFT JOIN does not return on Heroku PG

Tags: postgresql, heroku, psycopg2

I have a Heroku app that uses a psycopg [server-side cursor](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#server-side-cursors) together with a  `LEFT JOIN` query running on Heroku PG 13.5.

The query basically says “fetch items from one table, that don’t appear in another table”.

My data volume is pretty stable, and this has been working well for some time.

This week these queries stopped returning.  In `pg_stat_activity` they appeared as `active` indefinitely (17+ hours), similarly in `heroku pg:ps`. There appeared to be no deadlocks. All the [Heroku database metrics](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/monitoring-heroku-postgres) and logs appeared healthy.

If I run the same queries directly in the console (without a cursor) they return in a few seconds.

I was able to get it working again in the cursor by making the query a bit more efficient (switching from `LEFT JOIN` to `NOT EXISTS`; dropping one of the joins).

My questions are:

- Why might the original query perform fine in the console, but not return with a psycopg server-side cursor?
- How might I debug this?
- What might have changed this week to trigger the issue?

I can say that:

- However I write the query (`LEFT JOIN`, Subquery, `NOT EXISTS`), the query plan involves a Nested Loop Anti Join
- I don’t believe this is related to the [Heroku outage](https://status.heroku.com/incidents/2402) the following day (and which didn’t affect Heroku PG)
- Having Googled extensively, the closest thing I can find to a hypothesis to explain this is a post on the PG message boards from 2003 entitled [left join in cursor](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/2110.1055252123%40sss.pgh.pa.us) where the response is “Some plan node types don't cope very well with being run backwards.”

Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a cursor, PostgreSQL estimates that only 10% of the query result will be fetched quickly and prefers plans that return the first few rows quickly, at the expense of the total query cost.

You can disable this optimization by setting the PostgreSQL parameter `cursor_tuple_fraction` to 1.0.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question and your amazing work on Postgres! This is super-interesting.  I have not found if it's possible to adjust this setting on Heroku PG. If I try `heroku pg:settings:cursor_tuple_fraction 1.0` I get a warning that this is not a Heroku command, and a suggestion to try one of the [settings that they do support](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-settings). I will look into this further...

Comment: But I am sure that your application can run `SET cursor_tuple_fraction = 1.0;`.

Comment: Thanks.  You are right.  Will do some testing later today...

Comment: This is genius. `SET cursor_tuple_fraction = 1.0` works on a per-connection basis, and if I set this before running the original query it works as expected.  Very much appreciate your help.

Comment: @DerekHill If you want to make that setting persist across all sessions, you can use `ALTER DATABASE` or `ALTER ROLE` - this approach works fine on Heroku Postgres. There's no harm in setting it from the client though, and this is the preferred approach if different sessions might want different settings!

Comment: Thanks @JohnDalton,  that's extremely helpful.